# Intel HDMI Audio Out doesn't show up in Sound preferences

Tags: 10.10, sound, hdmi

**UPDATE:** Audio Out over HDMI was detected correctly and works fine after installing Ubuntu. The original question is below, but I'm now more interested in why it worked after the Install but not the Live CD. Is this a bug I should file?

---

I'm running the Ubuntu Maverick Live CD to make sure all the hardware on my laptop works before installing. The one problem I have is with HDMI Audio Out.

After I plug in the HDMI cable (or boot with it plugged in), I go to System > Preferences > Sound

Under the "Hardware" tab, I can select "Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output", but then the only entry under the "Output" tab is "Dummy Output." I don't hear any sound out of the TV speakers, and if I press "Test Speakers," the Sound dialog crashes.

here's the output of `aplay -l`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC269 Analog [ALC269 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC269 Digital [ALC269 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 3: INTEL HDMI 0 [INTEL HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

How can I get HDMI Audio Output to work?

Answer (score 1):

One difference between the live cd and your install could be the kernel modules that are loaded. You could check using `lsmod | grep hda` or `lsmod | grep hdmi` and see if there is any difference between the output on your install versus the live cd.

I don't have a maverick install, but I know with Lucid I have to explicitly load the newer ALSA drivers and kernel modules from a different PPA in order to get HDMI sound to work.